# C++ program in vscode not printing to terminal/console

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    std::cout << "hello"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am having trouble getting VScode configured.  The above program runs but does not print to the console. It's something with the debugger but I cannot figure out what. I got it to print, but when i restarted VSCode, it stopped working. Please help. Ive tried std::flush().
Wow so helpful everyone!

Comment: Your program produces the output `"hello\n"`. Of that there is no question. There is no need for `using namespace std;` since you use `std::cout` (good). I recommend compiling from the command line and ensuring your compiler is working properly, in your path, etc. With `gcc` use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11 -O3 -o nameforexe source.cpp` or with VS `cl /nologo /W3 /Ox /Fenameofexe /Tp source.cpp` Then run your code from the terminal. Once you know how to compile by hand, you can then teach an IDE how you want your code compiled. (instead of hoping it does it right)

Comment: You don't need `std::flush()`, but you do need to add `std::` to `endl`. `std::endl` causes a `flush()` on the output stream.

Comment: Exactly! It will print once compiled and linked to an executable. See either [Configure Visual Studio Code for Microsoft C++](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc) or [Get Started with C++ and Mingw-w64 in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) depending on the compiler if on windows, otherwise see the Linux setup at the same vscode side.